# What does "exit code 1" means in PerfView?

Tags: debugging, perfview

I try to take a heap snapshot of given process in PerfView. I selected file on disk with 144GB free space, at the time of the taking snapshot the process was reported to take 3GB of RAM and I selected to use Microsoft symbols.

After some time of working (i.e. taking snapshot), I got no file with dump and in the main window I saw status error stating "HeapDump failed with exit code 1". The problem I don't have a clue what this error means and how to solve the problem.

Comment: this code means ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION

Comment: @magicandre1981, thank you, this gave me an idea it can be not disk related, but arch related. However I was wrong, both 32-bit and 64-bit behave exactly the same way. I searched some more and found the bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/951 -- it looks it might be the same case (judging from code number).

Comment: this could be the same issue. So wait for a fix